# Java write a file - ignore system disk cache

Tags: java, io

I wish to write a file to disk and know that when the `writeFile()` operation has returned, the file has definitely been written to the disk and been written correctly.

Now I can do some sort of CRC check on the contents after the file has been written (read the file back and compare) but I am worried about system disk caching.

Is there a way I can write the file, skipping the disk cache, or flush the disk cache from Java?

I have purposefully not specified an environment because it would be nice to have a cross-environment solution. If not, my environment is a unix based one.

Answer (score 0):

`FileChannel.force()` will ensure that all data has made it to disk before returning.

From the [API doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html):

> Forces any updates to this channel's file to be written to the storage
>   device that contains it.
>
> If this channel's file resides on a local storage device then when
>   this method returns it is guaranteed that all changes made to the file
>   since this channel was created, or since this method was last invoked,
>   will have been written to that device. This is useful for ensuring
>   that critical information is not lost in the event of a system crash.

You can get hold of a files channel from `RandomAccessFile` or `FileOutputStream`, via `getChannel()`.

Comment: does this mean flushing the JVM buffers or the operating system buffers?

Comment: @cheetah It states that it works in the event of a crash, so it is all the way to the disk.